# How to locate truncate o files

Tags: c++, ld

I have a C++ build that ended abruptely (Jenkins job "Unexpected termination of the channel" error) and, after restart of the job I see an error like:

> ld: CMakeFiles/Folder.dir/Class.cpp.o: file not recognized: file truncated

I do not want to clean all therefore I have to launch the build, wait for another "file truncated" error, remove the file, rebuild, wait error, remove file, ...

I then searched on the web if this is a way to locate all truncated o files to remove them all at once, because now I think I will finally make clean and rebuild all since it may actually take less time.

Then, anyone knows if there is a way to do so ?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the file 0 bytes long?

Comment: Ah, I forgot to check that (I finally cleaned all), that would be a good start, I'll check that if I have the same issue in the future, thanks !

Comment: I ask because it's easy to search for 0-byte files, but it's harder to search for files that are "shorter than they should be"

Comment: Yes, that's what I understood, I was first looking for example for a tool that can say "this o file is corrupted" (not especially truncated) or something like that.